# Waiting until the AOG secondary node is in sync

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups

I'm helping ETL developers on offloading some SSIS workload from the SQL Server AOG primary node to the asynchronous secondary one.
The challenge comes when they need to write tables in the primary that almost immediately need to be part of big queries that they want to run in the async read-only replica.
I created this function designed for a two-nodes AOG that pretends to wait until the redo in the secondary finally flushes the changes from the log to the data file making the recently changed data in the primary available in the secondary.
Any feedback is welcome.

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.fnWaitUntilRedoInSecondary
(
    @pDatabaseName VARCHAR(255),
    @pTimeOutMS INT
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @vLastHardened NUMERIC(25, 0),
            @vLastRedone NUMERIC(25, 0),
            @vStartTime DATETIME2,
            @vEndTime DATETIME2,
            @vIsTimeOut BIT = 0,
            @vElapsedTime INT;
    SET @vStartTime = GETDATE();
    SELECT @vLastHardened = DRS.last_hardened_lsn
    FROM sys.dm_hadr_database_replica_states DRS
        INNER JOIN sys.availability_replicas AR
            ON DRS.replica_id = AR.replica_id
        INNER JOIN sys.dm_hadr_availability_replica_states HARS
            ON AR.group_id = HARS.group_id
               AND AR.replica_id = HARS.replica_id
    WHERE DB_NAME(DRS.database_id) = @pDatabaseName
          AND HARS.role_desc = 'PRIMARY';

    SET @vLastRedone = @vLastHardened - 1;

    WHILE @vLastHardened > @vLastRedone
    BEGIN
        SELECT @vLastRedone = DRS.last_redone_lsn
        FROM sys.dm_hadr_database_replica_states DRS
            INNER JOIN sys.availability_replicas AR
                ON DRS.replica_id = AR.replica_id
            INNER JOIN sys.dm_hadr_availability_replica_states HARS
                ON AR.group_id = HARS.group_id
                   AND AR.replica_id = HARS.replica_id
        WHERE DB_NAME(DRS.database_id) = @pDatabaseName
              AND HARS.role_desc = 'SECONDARY';
        SET @vEndTime = GETDATE();
        SELECT @vElapsedTime = DATEDIFF(ms, @vStartTime, @vEndTime);
        IF @vElapsedTime > @pTimeOutMS
            SET @vIsTimeOut = 1;
        IF @vIsTimeOut = 1
            BREAK;
    END;

    IF @vIsTimeOut = 1
        SET @vElapsedTime = -1;

    RETURN @vElapsedTime;
END;
```

Comment: What is the main issue that you're trying to solve, here?

Comment: One SSIS operation performs a large update over a table that needs to be consumed in the following step but connected to a secondary async replica. We have seen the secondary replica gets behing up to 2 minutes so the function would try to make the package to wait until the changes are fully available at that secondary node.

Comment: I don't see where you're passing in an LSN obtained on the primary for the last commit of the SSIS operation. Without that, you're not waiting for the redo changes to be completed, you're just checking there isn't a redo queue.

Comment: Thank you. Good catch. I was expecting the workflow would perform a CHECKPOINT on demand before consuming the function, but tracking the LSN would be better.